# How do I restore all replicated MySQL servers from a backup?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.7

I've got two MySQL 5.7 servers running with binary log replication. I now need to rollback to an older backup but I'm not sure what effect this will have on the binary log for replication.

If I just restore the backup on the primary, will the replica pick up the changes automatically? Or do I need to disable replication, restore the backup on both, then enable replication again, as if I were setting it up for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

I've done some tests and it looks like that restoring a `mysqldump` backup on the primary using `mysql` will get written into the binary log correctly and the changes automatically applied to the replicas. i.e.

```
mysql -u root -p < db-backup.sql
```

will work fine!